# Restrict user login on kernel level in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

It is possible (and rationally?) to restrict login for any user in a system after some event (for example logout of some user) by kernel haking? May be other ways are exists?
If it is possible, which part of kernel sources needs to be modified?

Comment: I will mount some encrypted drive and would not want anyone got access to it when I get out of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
touch /etc/nologin
```

Not wise to touch the kernel for this type of problem. See [man nologin](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_nologin). The "root" user can still log in.

Comment: Nice solution, but I need restrict access for root too (because when system is off /etc/shadow is available for many persons).

Comment: What do you mean /etc/shadow is 'available' when the system is off? If root login is disabled then how do you log in at all without rebooting?

Comment: It is about physical access to the disk.

Comment: As I mentioned above in the comments, I need to ensure the safety of the mounted my encrypted disk. Reboot is the best solution.

Comment: If /etc/shadow can be manipulated through physical disk access, so can the kernel itself (and the bootloader, for that matter, compromising full disk encryption). There really is no software substitute for physical access control to your sensitive servers.

Comment: Eureka! After touthing of /etc/nologin I can just change the root password. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not going to say that there is **no** way to accomplish your goal securely, but it doesn't seem like what you are proposing to do is likely to be secure.  Attempts to block logins are only effective if you can insure that any system which has the key to unlock the encryption is bound to honor those restrictions - ie, that it will use the config files in which you place them, and that the binaries comprising the system haven't been tampered with.

Answer (score 2):

Do this in userspace by manipulating the user database or changing the login program.  The necessary support is what is already in the kernel.